# NET 6 Web Api my unit test controller.Response is set with FeatureCollection but why are controller.Response.Headers are empty?

Tags: unit-testing, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, .net-6.0, response-headers

Unit testing a controller using FeatureCollection

```
features = new FeatureCollection();
features.Set<IHttpRequestFeature>(new HttpRequestFeature());
features.Set<IHttpResponseFeature>(new HttpResponseFeature());
features.Set<IHttpResponseBodyFeature>(new StreamResponseBodyFeature(Stream.Null));
var httpContext = new DefaultHttpContextFactory(_serviceProvider).Create(features);
controller.ControllerContext = new ControllerContext(httpContext, new RouteData(), new ControllerActionDescriptor());

var response = controller.CallPostMethod(1);

Assert.IsTrue(controller.Response.Headers.Count() > 0); // fail
```

If I run the same API call from Postman I see 5 response headers. Why are the response headers not being set in Unit Test?

Comment: What is `CallPostMethod`? Your controller action returns whatever the `return` statement inside it says. That's enough for a *unit* test. The ASP.NET Core converts that to an HTTP response. If you want the actual response, check how [WebApplicationFactory is used](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/test/integration-tests?view=aspnetcore-7.0#basic-tests-with-the-default-webapplicationfactory) to host the application in a test server and provide a test client. That's closer to integration than unit testing though.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos `CallPostMethod` returns an `ActionResult<T>` but that's not the focus of this test, the focus of this test is the headers because the headers must conform to a previous version of the API written in older version of net framework.

Comment: I already explained that actions don't return Http responses. The rest of the runtime convers the ActionResult or even `Customer` object you return into a response. If you want to check the actual response use WebApplicationFactory. After all, you aren't testing how a single action behaves but how the entire platform responds